# send image array for fetch formData in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, xmlhttprequest, fetch

With the console.log I can see the array imagenes and this is ok in proyect react-native, but on the server this variable does not arrive but if I get the array of dates and the variable description on the server

```js
let body = new FormData();
body.append('descripcion', 'dsadsadsa');
body.append('fechas[]', '2018-05-05');
body.append('fechas[]', '2015-05-05');

const {page1, page2, page3, page4, page5} = this.props.items;
body.append('imagenes[]', { uri: page2[2], name:'photo1.jpg', type: 'image/jpg'});

body.append('imagenes[]', { uri: page2[3], name:'photo2.jpg', type: 'image/jpg'});

body.append('imagenes[]', { uri: page2[4], name:'photo3.jpg', type: 'image/jpg'});

fetch(url, {
 method: 'post',
 headers: {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
 },
 body: body
})
 .then(res => res.text())
 .then(res => {
  console.log(res)
 }).catch((err) => {
  console.log('err', err)
 });
});
```

Thanks for help me!

Comment: Everything seems to be done correctly. Maybe you should add filename as well, but it probably doesn't matter. What's inside this.props.items? Perhaps the issue is on the serverside?

Comment: in this.props.items container info (inputs, calendar and images) from pages, var page2[2], page2[3], page2[4] container string uri image charge for client example in emlulator ios file:///Users/jhonerick/Library/Developer/.../A6A1ACEE-2510-43C6-968A-265617318A5D.jpg

Comment: solved, thanks for help me!

Comment: Are you using a debugger while sending the FormData?

Answer (score 0):

the code upload data and file (images) in RN this is ok, the bug in vars size file php.ini (memory_limit, upload_max_filesize, post_max_size).

in nginx, edit file nginx.conf add or update command

client_max_body_size 500M

Link https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-nginx-413-request-entity-too-large/